# I want to intentionally duplicate values in python

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have two different lists, one consists of list of random 12 dates on which I want to see sales
the second one consist of Unique Product ID the vendor sells.

I want to copy these dates in multiples of length of the second list.  Is there any easier way to do that?

Thanks for your help.

List A : Date

```
1. 1/1/20
2. 1/2/20
3. 1/3/20
4. 1/4/20
5. 1/5/20
6. 1/6/20
7. 1/7/20
8. 1/8/20
9. 1/9/20
10. 1/10/20
```

List B: Product ID:

```
1. BOM-12345
2. PEN-98765
3. BUN-45785
```

Now I want to copy these dates in front of the Product ID for 10 times per product ID.

Expected Output:

```
1. BOM-12345   1/1/20
2. BOM-12345   1/2/20
...                   ...
10. BOM-12345 1/10/20
11. PEN-98765  1/1/20
..     ..
20. PEN-98765 1/10/20
..    ..
30  BUN-45785 1/10/20
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome Ajinkya. It would help if you showed a sample input and expected output.

Comment: List A : Date 
1. 1/1/20
2. 1/2/20
3. 1/3/20
4. 1/4/20
5. 1/5/20
6. 1/6/20
7. 1/7/20
8. 1/8/20
9. 1/9/20
10. 1/10/20

List B: Product ID:
1. BOM-12345
2. PEN-98765
3. BUN-45785

Now I want to copy these dates in front of the Product ID for 10 times per product ID. 

Expected Output:
1. BOM-12345   1/1/20
2. BOM-12345   1/2/20
...                   ...
10. BOM-12345 1/10/20
11. PEN-98765  1/1/20
..     ..
20. PEN-98765 1/10/20
..    ..
30  BUN-45785 1/10/20

Comment: Use either `itertool.product` or `pd.MultiIndex.from_product`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using list comprehension, as so:

```py
listA = [--snip--]  # your first list.
listB = [--snip--]  # the second one.

listC = [[x + y for x in listB] for y in listA]  # pairs the two together, so the first list has a value for each value in the second.
```

This will make it far easier, albeit less readable. If you'd prefer readability, use a full for loop:

```py
listA = [--snip--]
listB = [--snip--]

listC = []

for date in listA:
    for item_id in listB:
        listC.append(date + item_id)
```

It's really whichever you prefer, but I like list comprehension more, in order to cut down on file size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lista = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\.\s', names=['index','Date'])
listb = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\.\s', names=['index','Product ID'])

df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([listb['Product ID'], lista['Date']], names=['Product ID', 'Date']).to_frame()
df_out = df.sort_index().reset_index()
print(df_out)
```

Output:

```
   Product ID     Date
0   BOM-12345   1/1/20
1   BOM-12345  1/10/20
2   BOM-12345   1/2/20
3   BOM-12345   1/3/20
4   BOM-12345   1/4/20
5   BOM-12345   1/5/20
6   BOM-12345   1/6/20
7   BOM-12345   1/7/20
8   BOM-12345   1/8/20
9   BOM-12345   1/9/20
10  BUN-45785   1/1/20
11  BUN-45785  1/10/20
12  BUN-45785   1/2/20
13  BUN-45785   1/3/20
14  BUN-45785   1/4/20
15  BUN-45785   1/5/20
16  BUN-45785   1/6/20
17  BUN-45785   1/7/20
18  BUN-45785   1/8/20
19  BUN-45785   1/9/20
20  PEN-98765   1/1/20
21  PEN-98765  1/10/20
22  PEN-98765   1/2/20
23  PEN-98765   1/3/20
24  PEN-98765   1/4/20
25  PEN-98765   1/5/20
26  PEN-98765   1/6/20
27  PEN-98765   1/7/20
28  PEN-98765   1/8/20
29  PEN-98765   1/9/20
```